# How to close USSD dialog programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, ussd

I tried a lot by using below code but don't get dismiss USSD dialog.

```
  Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
  sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
```